# Javascript Fetch API How to get user's post details when you click on the user?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I am trying to learn Javascript and I’m working on an exercise that fetches two different APIs, one for users and the other for posts. The exercise has two questions; first question is about fetching users and displaying them on the website. Users are fetched from this website https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users.

Second question is about fetching posts. When users are being displayed on the website you can select a user and get his posts. User’s posts are going to be displayed in a list. To fetch post/posts I need to use this url: /posts?userId={userId}. For example if you click on a user that has userId 5 you’re fetching his posts from following url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=5
I’m already finished with the first question, but need help to finish the second one. Can anyone help me out?

[How to place posts under the username?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXvzt.png)

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function (data) {
    appendData(data);
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log('error: ' + err);
});

function appendData(data) {
var mainContainer = document.getElementById("users");
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML =  data[i].username;

    li.dataset.userId = data[i].id;
    
    li.addEventListener('click', (event) => getPosts(event))
    mainContainer.appendChild(li);
}

}

function getPosts(event) {

var userId = event.target.dataset.userId;

fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${userId}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => renderPosts(json))
}

function renderPosts(posts) {
var titleContainer = document.getElementById("postTitle");
var bodyContainer = document.getElementById("postBody");
for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    var liTitle = document.createElement("li");
    var liBody = document.createElement("li");

    liTitle.innerHTML =  posts[i].title;
    liBody.innerHTML = posts[i].body;

    titleContainer.appendChild(liTitle);
    bodyContainer.appendChild(liBody);

//var title = posts.data.title;
//var body = posts.data.body;
//document.getElementById("postTitle").innerHTML = titleContainer;
//document.getElementById("postBody").innerHTML = bodyContainer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Javascript API Fetch Users and Posts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Users</h1>
    
    <div id="users"></div>
    <div id="postBody"></div>
    <div id="postTitle"></div>



    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, I'd think you'd want to add the `getPosts()` function to each of the users displayed, right? So that when you click the user, it gets that user's posts? So I'd change `appendData` to add an event listener to each `li` pointing to a function that calls `getPosts(userId)`, with the id of the user. So you'd need to change `getPosts` to take a `userId` argument, and pass it on in the URL you're fetching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some commented corrections in order for your code to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Javascript API Fetch Users and Posts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Users</h1>

    <div id="users"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            appendData(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
        });

    function appendData(data) {
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById("users");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML =  data[i].username;
            li.classList.add('item');
            li.dataset.userId = data[i].id;
            li.addEventListener('click', (event) => getPosts(event))
            mainContainer.appendChild(li);
        }

    }

    function cleanPosts() {
        var users = document.querySelectorAll('.item ul');
        for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if(users[i]) {
                users[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }

    function getPosts(event) {

        var userId = event.target.dataset.userId;

        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${userId}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => renderPosts(json, event.target))
    }

    function renderPosts(posts, target) {
        var postsList = target.childNodes[1];

        cleanPosts();

        if(postsList){
            postsList.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            var list = document.createElement("ul");

            for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {

                var item = document.createElement("li");
                var liTitle = document.createElement("strong");
                var liBody = document.createElement("p");

                liTitle.innerHTML = posts[i].title;
                liBody.innerHTML = posts[i].body;

                item.appendChild(liTitle);
                item.appendChild(liBody);
                list.appendChild(item);
            }

            target.appendChild(list);
        }

    }
```

Some of the things I've added and you might want to check out are the [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the use of [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: You need to fetch the users, I've edited the code and included it.

Comment: It's working now, but I found one problem regarding the posts. I removed the comments below console.log(posts). This gives me an an error when I click on the user. The error says posts.data is undefined.

Comment: Yes, thats because posts is an array not an object. There are several posts for each user. You can use the same approach you use for listing the users, a for loop through the posts array and then create an element so you can insert via innerHTML the post[i].title and post[i].body. After you've created the element and added the text you can append it to the postTitle and postBody divs. It's basically the same as the appendData function but in this case you will need to create two elements (title and body) and append to two different divs.

Comment: I wrote some code, but it didn't work. My users disappeared. This is the code I wrote, I would really appreciate it if you could help me. New edited code can be seen from my OP.

Comment: I looked at my code, its seems I forgot to add a bracket. One problem occurred, both title and body aren't disappearing when I select a new user, they instead get stacked on eachother. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Yes, you almost had it! I changed my answer and it solves the stacked problem. I commented the two divs you were using to render the title and body values and added a single div to render each title and body. Also modified the renderPosts function.

Comment: How can I move my posts under the username and create an unordered HTML list . I tried to move post div into the user div. I also renamed the post to ul and gave it id="post". But what happens instead is that posts appear over the username. Apparently li.dataset.userId causes the problem. How can I make post appear under the username and with an unordered list.

Comment: You pass the event.target which is you user element to the renderPosts function as a parameter. Inside your renderPosts functions you can append the unordered list. I edited the code to do that.

Comment: The problem now is that the unordered list are stacked on all users when I click through all of them. How can I make the list appear and be displayed for one username? For example when I click on Bret his post are displayed and when I click  on the other username, I still see Bret's post being displayed, they're not gone.

Comment: Add a class to each **li** inside the appendData function. Then create a new function to reset user posts values. Inside this function you want to get all users **li**elements, then loop through the elements and for each element remove it's second node(the unordered list), if they have one. You call this function inside the renderPosts(), at the top. This will clean all the content inside each user item before loading the specific posts into a user. I edited the code with this solution.

Comment: I made one last edit. The previous solution was fetching everytime you click on a user item even if you already clicked on that user and fetched that data, so it wasn't optimal. The last update takes care of that issue by hiding all the post list when clicking on a user and only fetching the posts if that user wasn't clicked before. Consider making this change. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    
    <div id="users"></div>
    <div id="postBody"></div>
    <div id="postTitle"></div>
```

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function (data) {
    appendData(data);
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log('error: ' + err);
});


function appendData(data) {
var mainContainer = document.getElementById("users");
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML =  data[i].username;

  li.setAttribute('id',data[i].id);
  li.addEventListener('click' ,getPosts,false);


    mainContainer.appendChild(li);
}
}


function getPosts(event) {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId${event.target.id}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
         console.log(response)
      //loop through response and  render  data 
    })
        
}
```